# pysc2 Starcraft - obs.observation returns KeyError

Tags: python, starcraftgym

I am trying to run various codes I found in the internet with `pysc2` Starcraft DeepMind AI agents. I often run into `KeyError: 'SOME-VALUE-HERE'` invoked by `obs.observation["SOME-VALUE-HERE"]`.

For example [this agent](https://github.com/skjb/pysc2-tutorial/blob/master/Building%20a%20Basic%20Agent/simple_agent_step2.py) and [this agent](https://github.com/deepmind/pysc2/issues/55) crash on `KeyError: 'minimap'` invoked by `obs.observation['minimap']`.

Other example is `KeyError: 'screen'` invoked by `observation["screen"]` when running [Siraj Raval's enjoy_mineral_shards script](https://github.com/llSourcell/A-Guide-to-DeepMinds-StarCraft-AI-Environment/blob/master/enjoy_mineral_shards.py).

It is very frustrating as I have not found anybody else running to this error and I really struggle with debugging in `pysc2` environment. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The codes were run with `pysc2` version `2.0.1`. One needs to downgrade to version `1.2` (relevant for mentioned examples).

```
pip install pysc2==1.2
```

(many thanks to discordapp Starcraft 2 AI community).